# Retrieving a Decimal value from DB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

if i give

```
p @work_orders.where(wo_number: 34305)
```

in my controller, o/p in terminal will be

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<WorkOrder id: 9168, shop_number: 3, ticket_number: 0, wo_number: 34305, date: "2014-04-02 02:24:57", time: "2000-01-01 15:54:57", customerPO: "", warranty_code: "1", market_source: "", sub_total: #<BigDecimal:bba2164,'0.72456E3',18(18)>, discount_type: "dollar", discount_amount: #<BigDecimal:bba20b0,'0.0',9(18)>, tax: #<BigDecimal:bba2038,'0.39E0',9(18)>, tax_exemptID: "", order_type: "regular", created_at: "2014-07-17 06:25:26", updated_at: "2014-07-17 06:25:26">]>
```

i'm trying to retrieve the value of subtotal..
This is so far i have tried..

```
p @work_orders.where(wo_number: 34305).first.sub_total
```

that resulted in error

```
undefined method `sub_total' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: In your `WorkOrder` model attribute `sub_total` but  you try call `subtotal`.

Comment: ah.. Couldn't see it. Why `nil`? That's *crazy*.

Comment: So no solution????///

Comment: How are you generating @work_orders at the console? What do you get with: WorkOrder.where(wo_number: 34305).first.subtotal

Comment: ReggieB Same thing... i had one code like @work_orders = WorkOrder.all

Comment: Could your show your `sub_total` method?

Comment: @Stefan what?.. its a column inside the table Work Order

Comment: @NidhinSG sorry, I thought it was a custom method

Comment: Can you try this `WorkOrder.where(wo_number: 34305).first.sub_total`?

Comment: What does `WorkOrder.where(wo_number: 34305).first` return?

Comment: @Pavan Getting same error :(

Comment: @NidhinSG what does `WorkOrder.where(wo_number: 34305).first` (without `.sub_total`) return?